# Excel formula...to many arguments

Tags: excel

New here, and somewhat of a novice...this is the excel formula that returns the information i need, however when I nest it...I get an error message saying I have to many arguments...Is there a way to simply the formula to get the same information, so that it won't contain to many arguments?

=IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=1),Muntins!K71(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=1),Muntins!J71, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=2),Muntins!K72(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=2),Muntins!J72, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=3),Muntins!K73(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=3),Muntins!J73, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=4),Muntins!K74(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=4),Muntins!J74, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=5),Muntins!K75(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=5),Muntins!J75, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=6),Muntins!K76(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=6),Muntins!J76, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=7),Muntins!K77(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=7),Muntins!J77, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=8),Muntins!K78(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=8),Muntins!J78, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=9),Muntins!K79(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=9),Muntins!J79, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=10),Muntins!K80(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=10),Muntins!J80, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=11),Muntins!K81(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=11),Muntins!J81, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=12),Muntins!K82(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=12),Muntins!J82, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=13),Muntins!K83(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=13),Muntins!J83, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=14),Muntins!K84(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=14),Muntins!J84, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=15),Muntins!K85(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=15),Muntins!J85, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=16),Muntins!K86(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=16),Muntins!J86, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=17),Muntins!K87(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=17),Muntins!J87, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=18),Muntins!K88(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=18),Muntins!J88 IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=19),Muntins!K89(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=19),Muntins!J89, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=20),Muntins!K90(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=20),Muntins!J90, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=21),Muntins!K91(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=21),Muntins!J91, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=22),Muntins!K92(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=22),Muntins!J92, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=23),Muntins!K93(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=23),Muntins!J93, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=24),Muntins!K94(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=24),Muntins!J94, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=25),Muntins!K95(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=25),Muntins!J95, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=26),Muntins!K96(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=26),Muntins!J96, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=27),Muntins!K97(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=27),Muntins!J97, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=28),Muntins!K98(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=28),Muntins!J98, IF(AND(Muntins!A1=1,Pricing!B4=29),Muntins!K99(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=29),Muntins!J99,)))))))))

Thanks in advance for any help,

MC

Comment: I can't possibly imagine any scenario where this formula is optimized for whatever you're trying to do. Perhaps you can explain what you're trying to do, provide some sample data (and expected output) and someone can guide you to a better solution... Also, you mention that "this formula works" but then you say it doesn't work when you "nest it". So, it's not clear whether this is the *working* version, or whether this is the *not working* version. Please clarify by making revisions to your question above.

Comment: 1. Try Excel VBA; 2. Save temporary results in cells and make use of auto-increment feature.

Comment: Also, looks like you're (probably) missing logical operators and commas e.g., here: `Muntins!K71(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=1)`, repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Well at the very least, you have a trailing comma at the end that is causing at least one additional argument to exist:

```
Muntins!K99(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=29),Muntins!J99,))))))
```

But even removing this comma, I can't really reverse engineer what you're trying to do, and it appears as I noted in comments above that you're missing some important logic, for example, `Muntins!K99(Muntins!A1=2,Pricing!B4=29)` which is repeatedly used (onlyo with different vals inside the parentheses) appears to be very wrong, and should probably be another `,If(And(...` expression.

Based on that, I **think** I grok what you're trying to do, and if I'm correct, then **you can replace that entire abomination with something like**:

`=If(Muntins!A1=1,Offset(Muntins!$K$70,Pricing!B4,1),IF(Muntins!A1=2,Offset(Muntins!$J$70,Pricing!B4,1),"Error")`

**How does this work?** Well, the value in `Pricing!B4` is what you're using to increment which row in column K or J you want to return data from. So rather than set up a crazy rat's nest of nested `If` statements, we can just use that value to feed the `Offset` function.

Then, the only condition we're worried about is the value of `Muntins!A1`, which we can do in two `If` statements, if we break it down in to pseudo-code it may make more sense to explain:

```
     If (Muntins!A1=1) Then
         Return the value form Muntins!K70 offset by number of rows given by Pricing!B4
     ElseIf (Muntins!A1=2) Then
         Return the value form Muntins!J70 offset by number of rows given by Pricing!B4
     Else
         (return some error message)
     End If
```